# Convert MySQL timestamp or PHP datetime to local client datetime using Angular JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, datetime

I am trying to convert MySQL timestamp and PHP timestamp to local client time zone base datetime to show on the chat messages 
mean in database we will have both PHP datetime and MySQL timestamp store with the message but I want to display that datetime according the user local time zone if he is in america then the timezone will be according to his time

And if he is Pakistan or SoutAfrica the datetime should show on the message will be his local datetime 
Here is my code

```
<span class=""> at <% chatData.date_created | date:'MMM d,yyyy hh:mm:ss a'   %> </span>
```

but this is displaying the same date-time which is stored in date_created column 
`2016-01-11 17:54:27` the actuall value not this this datetime

```
 Jan 11, 2015 8:40:23 AM
```

here is my angular app initialization i have added the moment-with-locales.js file

```
var app = angular.module('ChatboxApp', ['ngtimeago','elif'],function($interpolateProvider){
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>'); 
}).filter('momentFilter', function() {
    return function(dateString, format) {
        return moment(dateString).format(format);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a filter using moment.js:

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', [])
  .filter('momentFilter', function() {
    return function(dateString, format) {
        return moment(dateString).format(format);
    };
});
```

Then apply that filter in your HTML:

```
<h4>Date formatted: {{yourdate | momentFilter:'MMM d,yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}</h4>
```

Here is the working plunker: [plnkr.co/edit/wWnnzr2c7scSVgwbMIgu?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/wWnnzr2c7scSVgwbMIgu?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @Tomislav  which files i need to add into my project from moment.js folder for this.

Comment: it two one downloads avaiable one moment.js and other is moment+locales.js

Comment: it is giving me this error Syntax Error: Token '17' is an unexpected token at column 12 of the expression [2016-01-11 17:54:27 | momentFilter:'MMM d,yyyy hh:mm:ss'] starting at [17:54:27 | momentFilter:'MMM d,yyyy hh:mm:ss].
for this datetime 
<h4>Date formatted: <% 2016-01-11 17:54:27 | momentFilter:'MMM d,yyyy hh:mm:ss' %></h4>

Comment: i have added my moment.js code in my question please kindly check it

Comment: change: date:'MMM d,yyyy hh:mm:ss a'     to momentFilter:'MMM d,yyyy hh:mm:ss a'

Comment: the plunker is working but the my problem here is this that mysql and php time are storing their own server datetime in the database.Mean to say if i insert a message now then my hosting serve will save their own server datetime mean currently that is 2016-01-11 13:49:07 but i want this datetime to be conveted into my local date time which will be  2016-01-12 00:52:06 this is the problem i am facing